# Ender 5 (Plus) - Gantry not square to frame, how to fix?

Tags: creality-ender-5, mechanics

How would one go about squaring the gantry relative to the frame?

Referring to the image below, distance A and distance B are not equal.

Also would this account for the reason why when I attempt to print a circle it is not perfectly circular, and when I try to print a square, it is tilted?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and I was surprised with the lack of the information about this topic on the Internet. So, here is how I managed to make the gantry absolutely parallel.

1. Make sure your frame is square:
   [image: Frame]
   If it's not square, try to loosen all the screws (don't forget about those holding the motherboard) and tighten everything again. Use a level and a carpenter's square.
2. Loosen the shaft couplings on the Y axis. Those:
   [image: Shaft couplers]
3. Loosen these four screws:
   [image: Gantry screws]
4. Loosen these eccentric nuts:
   [image: Eccentric nuts]
5. Now your gantry should be completely relieved and allow you to make the adjustments
6. Move the gantry to the front side of the printer so that the wheels touch these corners:
   [image: Aluminum corners]
   If your frame is square, it would mean that X and Y axes would be perpendicular to each other.

   Don't push the gantry to hard to prevent wheels damage!
7. Now tighten the screws from the second step, trying to still hold the gantry touching the corners at both sides:
   [image: Gantry screws]
8. Then, tighten the shaft coupling from the first step, while still ensuring everything is perpendicular and parallel.
   [image: Shaft couplers]
9. Finally, adjust the eccentric nuts from the fourth step. Make sure they all touch the profile and that they all have the same rolling friction.
   [image: Eccentric nuts]
10. Check everything one more time and you're done. Now your gantry is completely squared. Enjoy your skew-less prints!

---

- Ender-5 Pro 3D model: https://grabcad.com/library/creality-ender-5-pro-1

Comment: Thanks for this! Really clearly presented with the red/green and graphics.

Comment: This fixed my first layer being skewed, but now my z-axis is scewed when it was not before this. Specifically the z-axis skews on the left side of the print, but is correct on the right, so it is like my print twists as it grows on the z-axis, but only on the left side. I am ready to take a hammer to the thing. I have had the ender 5 for a month, and have only stopped tinkering to sleep and I still cannot get useful prints.

Comment: Strange. There is no such thing as "Z-skew". Simply use the knobs under your bed to make you bed parallel to the gantry.

Answer (score 2):

> How would one go about squaring the gantry relative to the frame?

You first need to make sure that the cube/box frame is square. Once this is done, you need to check whether the gantry is still not perpendicular/parallel to the top frame. If not, you need to loosen the couplers at the front that control the Y movement of the printer. See if you can reposition the gantry to be square to the frame. If that doesn't work, you need to fiddle with the bolts that hold the wheels of the X-Y carriages so that the gantry will become aligned with the top of the frame.

> Also would this account for the reason why when I attempt to print a circle it is not perfectly circular, and when I try to print a square, it is tilted?

Yes, a skew gantry causes skew prints, i.e. squares become parallelograms, and circles become oval. There is another solution to fix this in firmware, but, the preferred method is to mechanically fix the issue.